# Vim: Substitute only in syntax-selected text areas

Tags: vim

The exact problem: I have a source in C++ and I need to replace a symbol name to some other name. However, I need that this replace the symbol only, not accidentally the same looking word in comments or text in "".

The source information what particular language section it is, is enough defined in the syntax highlighting rules. I know they can fail sometimes, but let's state this isn't a problem. I need some way to walk through all found occurrences of the phrase, then check in which section it is found, and if it's text or comment, this phrase should be skipped. Otherwise the replacement should be done either immediately, or by asking first, depending on well known `c` flag.

What I imagine would be at least theoretically possible is:

- Having a kinda "callback" when doing substitution (called for each phrase found, and requesting the answer whether to substitute or not), or extract the list of positions where the phrase has been found, then iterate through all of them
- Extract the name of the current "hi-linked" syntax highlighting rule, which is used to color the text at given position

Is it at all possible within the current features of vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with a `:help sub-replace-expression`, you can evaluate arbitrary expressions in the replacement part of `:substitute`. Vim's `synID()` and `synstack()` functions allow you to get the current syntax element.

Luc Hermitte has an implementation that omits replacement inside strings, [here](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/substitute_unless_string.vim). You can easily adapt this to your use case.

Comment: That's almost perfect what I need, just one more question:

There is `hi def link` which links `String` to `Constant`. I can obtain the direct syntax element name, which can be `cString` or `cCppString` or even another kinda string, or do `synIDtrans()` on the ID and get the final resolution, which is surprisingly `Constant` (not `String`). Is there a way to obtain the "list of syn links", or at least the "direct sibling" (not the final resolution) of the linked hi items? If not, I probably can do fine with having "String" contained in the name, but it looks a little bit ugly.

Comment: Unfortunately, you only get the name of the syntax element (`cString`), and the final, effective highlight group name (`Constant`). I would go with checking that the former has `String` somewhere inside.

Comment: Ok, that should be still good enough. The problem is that there's a clear link from String to Constant in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syncolor.vim...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433), you can define a short predicate function, e.g. matching comments and constants (strings, numbers, etc.):

```
function! CommentOrConstant()
    return ingo#syntaxitem#IsOnSyntax(getpos('.'), '^\%(Comment\|Constant\)$')
endfunction
```

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) now provides a `:SubstituteIf` command that works like `:substitute`, but also takes a predicate expression. With that, it's very easy to do a replacement anywhere except in comments or constants:

```
:%SubstituteIf/pattern/replacement/g !CommentOrConstant()
```